# should I use Instagram postgressql id generator techniques for my project

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, web-development-server

If my epoch time is 2019-11-11. For how many years can I generate unique I'd using Instagram technique. Can someone explain how this algorithm works.
https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c?gi=a23b1b9c6107

Answer (score 1):

This information in in the article you liked:

> Each of our IDs consists of:
>
> - 41 bits for time in milliseconds (gives us 41 years of IDs with a custom epoch)

Therefore:

- 41 bits gives 2^41=2199023255552 possibilities,
- each day has 1000*60*60*24=86400000 milliseconds,
- they can generate them for 2199023255552/86400000≈25451 days,
- which means 25451/365.25≈69 years.

If you need the exact answer - the algorithm with epoch of "2019-11-11 00:00 UTC" is good until July 17th, 2089, afternoon:

```
=> select '2019-11-11 00:00 UTC'::timestamptz+2^41*'1ms'::interval;
2089-07-17 15:47:35.552+00
```